# How to make a model class observable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, frameworks, inotifypropertychanged

**Scenario**

I get a model class from an external component or a code part where I do not want to alter something.
I'd like to bind this class to some WPF UI.
I also would like to refresh the UI if this model gets altered.

**Question**

Do I really need to write a wrapper class all the time, that creates PropertyChanged events for each setter?
How could I prevent to write all this clue coding manually?

What started like this ...

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool CurrentlyLoggedIn { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

... will always be bloated like so

```
public class UserObservableWrapper : IUser, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.innerUser.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == this.innerUser.Name)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.innerUser.Name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Name" );
        }
    }

    public bool CurrentlyLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return innerUser.CurrentlyLoggedIn;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals( innerUser.CurrentlyLoggedIn ))
            {
                return;
            }
            innerUser.CurrentlyLoggedIn = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "CurrentlyLoggedIn" );
        }
    }

    private readonly IUser innerUser;

    public UserObservableWrapper( IUser nonObservableUser )
    {
        this.innerUser = nonObservableUser;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }
    }
}
```

There must be a more intelligent way of doing that!?

Comment: I've heard of people using Aspect Oriented techniques to inject such functionality into code. Checkout www.PostSharp.net. The landing page even mentions INotifyPropertChanged specifically.

Comment: @Crowcoder http://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged this looks awesome, but it does require him to be able to edit the model classes, and as he specified, they come from an external component. Do you know if `PostSharp` has the ability to do this at runtime?

Comment: @Moti I am not very knowledgeable myself so I hesitate to do more than just say "check this out, it may useful", but I see they do Load-time weaving and Run-time static weaving which sounds like there is no need to modify the actual code of the library you are using. http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/runtime-weaving

Comment: So you have the M in MVVM, which you want to bind to the V. It looks like you are missing out on the VM part, which should expose properties to your V for binding. Those VM properties may then `get` a property on your M, but binding your M directly to the V isn't a great idea. Have a look at http://xamlpatterns.com/stateless-view-models for ideas (you don't need to use his framework)

Comment: @Mashton: Hmm, no, not quite. I didn't want to bind my view directly to my model. I wanted to avoid writing dump boiler plate code again and again.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you then. It was probably this line in your question "I'd like to bind this class to some WPF UI"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't happen a lot of times in your code I would recommend you to do the boilerplate code.

Otherwise, you can use this [cool piece of code](http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged) from Ayende to generate a proxy class that would auto implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you (including event raising).
Usage would look like this:

```
IUser userProxy = DataBindingFactory.Create<User>();
```